# Juju not recognizing MAAS defined spaces

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I'm trying to deploy percona-cluster and binding shared-db to internal space. Juju and MAAS version being used is 2.0.
When i run this command:

```
juju deploy cs:percona-cluster --series xenial mysql --config=openstackha.cfg --to lxd:13 --bind "shared-db=internal-api"
```

It fails with the following error:

```
ERROR cannot add application "mysql": unknown space "internal-api" not valid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, the issue in my case was, juju put all subnets in the default space (space-0) though i had spaces defined in MAAS.
So, I created required spaces using Juju and associated relevant networks to each.

To see available spaces to juju

```
juju spaces
```

To create a space and add existing networks, run

```
juju add-space <space-name> <network-cidr-to-add-to-this-space>
```